# How to use map and filter in JS and TS to get a string array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have a file called `MasterSection` that defines what a section is, it contains the logic for sections. Various other sections (food section, tv section) derive from the `MasterSection` logic. In the `MasterSection` i have an interface called `SectionInfo` which has properties of a Section such as id, size, etc. Now for the current section that im working on, i need to access the properties of this interface (SectionInfo). To do that i have to first get the selected sections. To do this, we use the a function in the `MasterSection` called `getSelectedSections`. The following function is located in the section im working on and where my problem lies:

### getSectionInfo in CafeSection.ts

```
 function getSectionInfo(sectionType: string): number[] {
    const sectionInfo: MasterSection.SectionInfo[] = MasterSection.Model.Sections.SectionInfo;
    const selectedIds: number[] = MasterSection.getSelectedSections(MasterSection.Model.SectionType.CafeSection.Key);

    const cafeInfo = sectionInfo
        .filter((selectedSectionPks: MasterSection.SectionInfo) => selectedSectionPks.indexOf( /*What goes here??*/ !== -1))
        .map((selectedSectionPks: MasterSection.SectionInfo) => $'{selectedSectionPks.id}{selectedSectionPks.size}"); //Is this correct?

     return cafeInfo;

}
```

### getSelectedSections in MasterSection.ts

```
export function getSelectedSections(sectionType: string): number[] {
    return MasterSection.SelectedSections
        .filter((selectedSection: MasterSection.SelectedSections) => selectedSection.SectionKey ===
            sectionKey)
        .map((selectedSection: MasterSection.SelectedSections) => selectedSection.Id);
}
```

### SectionInfo in MasterSection.ts

```
 export interface SectionInfo {
    Id: string;
    DaysVisited: string;
    createdBy: string;
    size: string;
}
```

I am trying to get the properties of the SectionInfo however its been a long time and it seems i am missing some stuff. I have commented // the sections that i need help with in the code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your input and expected output?

Comment: @CertainPerformance not sure what you mean. User selects all sections, then i print those sections. I have a window that is opened with the selected sections. I need to pass the SectionInfo  properties as strings to this window. In order to do that i have to extract the SectionInfo properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `filter` line, I think you may be looking for:

```
.filter((selectedSectionPks: MasterSection.SectionInfo) =>
    selectedIds.indexOf(parseInt(selectedSectionPks.Id)) !== -1)
```

If I understand correctly, `selectedIds` has the array of selected IDs, so for each `SectionInfo` object (bound to `selectedSectionPks`), you want to check if its ID is in that array.  I put in the `parseInt` because you've declared the `Id` property of `SectionInfo` as a string but `selectedIds` is a `number[]`.  Check that this is what you intend.

For the `map` line, if you want to make a string containing the `Id` and `size` fields, the correct syntax for a string interpolation would be:

```
.map((selectedSectionPks: MasterSection.SectionInfo) =>
    `${selectedSectionPks.Id}${selectedSectionPks.size}`);
```

Of course, you might want to add a separator between the two fields to make this easier to parse on the other side.

Comment: Yes sir you got it! Before I mark you as the correct answer. For the map part, is my syntax correct? Each selected section contains a SectionInfo so I'm getting them as strings to populate in window.open. Also the number part was incorrect thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In the map, suppose I want size and Id properties what would be the syntax for that? The output would have to be strings since they are passed to window.open

Comment: See the updated answer for an example of the `map` part.